# How to change setState of object in other object in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, setstate

I've created a state of objects in React, but I need to increase an other object into the same state. However, i can't use the `setState()` property because its causes a re-render (infinite loop).

My state:

```
const [testObject, setTestObject] = useState({
       id: 0,          
       telephone: 123,            
       personalData: {
            name: '',
            alias: '',
            gender: ''
        }
    })
```

The error:

```
Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

I tried to find a solution for it, but i can't solve it:

```
setTestObject({...testObject, personalData: {
        ...testObject, name: 'McDonnell DC-10'
    }})
```

Where am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify you're using personalData, you're along the right lines.

```
setTestObject({...testObject, personalData: {
        ...testObject.personalData, name: 'McDonnell DC-10'
    }})
```

You can even use the old state as a parameter for better performance.

```
setTestObject(testObject => { return {...testObject, personalData: {
        ...testObject.personalData, name: 'McDonnell DC-10'
    }}})
```

Comment: I tried using this, but have the same problem yet. But, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to avoid the infinite loop is add the code inside a `useEffect()`, like this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    setTestObject({
      ...testObject,
      personalData: {
        ...testObject.personalData,
        name: 'McDonnell DC-10',
      },
    });
  }, []);
```

Also I guess you want to *update* the property `name` and no to add the whole object again inside *personalData*, that is why you need to use `...testObject.personalData`